# SQL COUNT ignoring a column

Tags: sql, count

I have a doubt on a SQL query:

I have the following result from a query:

```
select distinct eb.event_type_id, eb.status from eid.event_backlog eb order by 1

|event_type_id|status    |
|-------------|----------|
|1            |SUCCESS   |
|2            |SUCCESS   |
|2            |ERROR     |
|3            |SUCCESS   |
|3            |ERROR     |
|4            |SUCCESS   |
```

i would like to obtain this result doing a distinct on the status:

```
|event_type_id|count  |
|-------------|-------|
|1            |1      |
|2            |2      |
|3            |2      |
|4            |1      |
```

but the only way that I see to obtain this result is doing the following query:

```
select
    eb.event_type_id,
    count(1)
from
    (
    select
        distinct eb.event_type_id, eb.status
    from
        eid.event_backlog eb
    order by
        1) eb
group by
    eb.event_type_id
```

I don't like to use an nestled query, there is another way to obtain what i want?

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. You could do that by showing some lines of "CREATE TABLE ...." and "INSERT ...".

Comment: Simply `count(distinct eb.status)`

Comment: What is your intention with `order by 1`?

Comment: "I don't like to use an nestled query" -- What's wrong with a subquery? They are quite handy.

Comment: Derived tables are handy, but some (far from all) dbms products have problems optimizing them.

Comment: @RubberBee i put the order condition only to order the result :)

Comment: What kind of ordering to you expect from `order by 1`? Order by 1st "column" (which one?), order numerically? Please describe the expected difference between with and without `order by 1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply `count(distinct eb.status)`, i.e.

```
select
    eb.event_type_id,
    count(distinct eb.status)
from eid.event_backlog eb
group by
    eb.event_type_id
```